# Stuck with this PS Script

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains millions of records
I want to find out from each line that does not start with string + that line number (String starts with double quote 01/01/2019)

Can you help me modify this code?

```
Get-Content "(path).txt" | Foreach { if ($_.Split(',')[-1] -inotmatch "^01/01/2019") { $_; } }
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide a few examples of the `path.txt` file and what we are looking at so we can see if your code is even viable.

Comment: "(path).txt" I meant like "‪C:\Userssomeone\Desktop\script.ps1"

Comment: Text file contains just data such as "01/01/2019",Field1, Field2, etc"

Comment: Have a look at piping the content to [ConvertFrom-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-6) so you don't have to split on the last line

Comment: You should use Where-Object instead of foreach. You Aren’t doing anything to each object, you are just wanting to filter results basically. What does your text file content actually look like??

Comment: @m0lochwalker File content looks like "01/01/2019  22:42:00", "column1", "column2", etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments the content will look something like the array.
So you want to read the content, filter it, and get the resulting line from that content:

```
# Get the content

# $content = Get-Content -Path 'pathtofile.txt'
$content = @('field1,field2,field3', '01/01/2019,b,c') 

# Convert from csv
$csvContent = $content |  ConvertFrom-Csv 

# Add your filter based on the field
$results = $csvContent | Where-Object { $_.field1 -notmatch '01/01/2019'}  | % { $_ }

# Convert your results back to csv if needed
$results | ConvertTo-Csv
```

If performance is an issue then .net would handle millions of records with [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) just like [PowerBi](https://github.com/DevScope/powerbi-powershell-modules).

```
# install CsvHelper 
nuget install CsvHelper

# import csvhelper 
import-module CsvHelper.2.16.3.0\lib\net45\CsvHelper.dll

# write the content to the file just for this example
@('field1,field2,field3', '01/01/2019,b,c') | sc -path "c:\temp\text.csv"

$results = @()
# open the file for reading 
try {
$stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead("c:\temp\text.csv")
$sr = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($stream)
$csv = [CsvHelper.CsvReader]::new($sr)

# read in the records
while($csv.Read()){
    # add in the result 
    $result= @{}     

    [string] $value = "";

    for($i = 0; $csv.TryGetField($i, [ref] $value ); $i++) {
        $result.Add($i, $value);
    }
    # add your filter here for the results
    $results.Add($result)
}
# dispose of everything once we are done
}finally {

    $stream.Dispose();
    $sr.Dispose();
    $csv.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't need to convert to csv and here's I am having an issue with the script: Get-Content "C:\Users\Someone\Test.txt"  | Where-Object { $_.field1 -notmatch '^01/01/2019'}     I want to find result where each line of this file does not start with January first..but somehow I'm getting results that starts with January first

Comment: Please provide some sample content as I have no idea what your data looks like.

Comment: Content for each line starts with "01/01/2019 22:42:13","Column2              ","Column2                                     ","                    ","                              ","  However when importing text file into database, because of delimeter issue, some of the lines break, and doesn't start with "01/01/2019" I want to find which line does not start with that

Comment: In unix, it would be something like awk '!/^01/01/2019 {print;}

Comment: Do you need notmatch or can you use not like ; ```@('field1,field2,field3', '"01/01/2019 22:42:13","Column2 ","Column2 "," "," ","') | ? { $_ -notlike '*01/01/2019*'}``` ?

Comment: Can be both. Any command that tells Each line that does not start with "01/01/2019" because this text file has millions of rows. Majority starts with "01/01/2019", but some lines probably has some content of its previous line, but because of bad delimter, it moved on the next line, so the line starts with non "01/01/2019". It is those content that I want to find. Eliminating lines that start with "01/01/2019 ......"

Comment: Can it be something like Where-Object {-not $_.StartsWith ?

Comment: maybe : (! ( $_.StartsWith() )

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question and comments, you are dealing with a headerless CSV file it seems. Because the file *contains millions of records*, I think using `Get-Content` or `Import-Csv` could slow down too much. Using `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` would then be faster.

If indeed each line starts with a quoted date, you could use various methods of figuring out if the line start with `"01/01/2019` or not. Here, I use the `-notlike` operator:

```
$fileIn  = "D:\your_text_file_which_is_in_fact_a_CSV_file.txt"
$fileOut = "D:\your_text_file_which_is_in_fact_a_CSV_file_FILTERED.txt"

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($fileIn)) {
    if ($line -notlike '"01/01/2019*') {
        # write to a NEW file
        Add-Content -Path $fileOut -Value $line
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Judging from your comment, you are apparently using an older .NET framework, as the `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` became available as of [version 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.0).

In that case, the below code should work for you:

```
$fileIn  = "D:\your_text_file_which_is_in_fact_a_CSV_file.txt"
$fileOut = "D:\your_text_file_which_is_in_fact_a_CSV_file_FILTERED.txt"

$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($fileIn)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($fileOut)
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($line -notlike '"01/01/2019*') {
        # write to a NEW file
        $writer.WriteLine($line)
    }
}
$reader.Dispose()
$writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Logic of your script makes sense and you are in the right track. I wanted to test, but when I insert your script, I get "Method invocation failed because [System.IO.File] doesn't contain a method named 'ReadLines'."

Comment: @slayers The `ReadLines` method is available since .NET framework version 4.0. If your version is below that, I have updated my answer to give you an alternative.

Comment: Not to be petty, but I don't see what this script is doing that the native Powershell one-liner I provided is not. I do not see the need for using a While loop and If statements, when literally all slayers asked was to get lines that do not contain a specific date. Maybe performance is the issue. But the result slayers asked for is easily done per my post.

Answer (score 0):

My .txt file looks like this...

**date,col2,col3

"01/01/2019 22:42:00", "column2", "column3"

"01/02/2019 22:42:00", "column2", "column3"

"01/01/2019 22:42:00", "column2", "column3"

"02/01/2019 22:42:00", "column2", "column3"**

This command does exactly what you are asking...

```
Get-Content -Path C:\myFile.txt | ? {$_ -notmatch "01/01/2019"} | Select -Skip 1
```

The output is:

**"01/02/2019 22:42:00", "column2", "column3"

"02/01/2019 22:42:00", "column2", "column3"**

I skipped the top row. If you want to deal with particular columns, change myFile.txt to a .csv and import it.

Comment: In response to your comment on my answer: It is perfectly fine to have more than one answer on a single question.  Besides, I posted mine well before you did and added new code as per the OPs comment. BTW. Your answer expects the file to have column headers where the OP commented that it does not. Also, when using the `-notmatch`, you need to be aware that in other columns there may be dates aswell and the question is all about skipping lines where the **first** column differs from Januari 1st, 2019. Without anchoring and including the first double-quote, your answer will then fail I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi @Theo. Again, not trying to be petty or feisty. I did address the header scenario, and if slayers data does not contain headers, using Get-Content is fine. The data as described to me by slayer does not contain dates in other columns. I asked what it looked like, and this is what they described. Switch my suggestion to use -notlike "01/01/2019*" if you prefer, it will do the same thing if the data is as described. I also do not see where slayers said there are no headers. This excerpt from their comment below would suggest otherwise..."Where-Object { $_.field1 -notmatch '^01/01/2019'}"

Comment: @Theo at any rate, good work with the .NET objects and all. And thanks for being helpful in the community. Have a good one!

Comment: Thanks, although the second comment by the OP states _Text file contains just data such as "01/01/2019",Field1, Field2, etc"_. You're right about him leaving us in the dark as to what is in the other columns, so better safe than sorry don't you think?

Comment: Right, but he also uses "...$_.field1..." which in this context would be a column name/header. And yes, better safe than sorry. My point was this can be achieved with a simple one-liner and I was seeing relatively complex scripts being offered as a solutions. Anyway I hope slayers get what they need.